# How to validate GCP Pub/sub push subscription token?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-platform, jwt, openid-connect, google-cloud-pubsub

We are new to the GCP. We have set up a Pub/Sub queue that has a push subscription to an external webhook (ASP.NET Web API) with authentication enabled. This gives us a bearer token in the HTTP post call.

It is unclear for me if:

- A. I need to request a token using the service account `.json` file first and compare it with the bearer token that Pub/Sub sends in the webhook.
- B. I only need to validate the token from pubsub with `GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(token, settings)`?

Either possibility works, I am just unsure about the security implications. Option B is simple, but is it really secure? Isn't possible to tamper with this?

Comment: The `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>` is a Google OAuth (OIDC) Identity Token. This link shows you how to verify: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth Google has many more pages, example code, etc on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can even use Microsoft’s libraries to validate the token, [as explained in this ASP.NET blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/). Given the [audience you configured with the push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#setting_up_for_push_authentication), use this code:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
{
    Audience = "",  // The audience you configured the token to have 
    Authority = "https://accounts.google.com", 
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true
});
```

Comment: I actually did just that and ran into a new problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902686/why-does-jwt-issuer-signing-key-validation-always-return-valid