# Why does JWT issuer signing key validation always return valid?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I have a Google Pub/Sub push subscription that sends a JWT token to the endpoint. The endpoint needs to validate this token. From Google documentation, I need to check the issuer, the audience and the  signature. This works fine, except for whatever I add to IssuerSigningKey(s), the token is valid. I expected this to break whenever I e.g. remove a part of the key.

I tried all kinds of different values for IssuerSigningKey and IssuerSigningKeys. No matter what, I get a valid response. Changing e.g. the domain or audience parameters does return a 401 Unauthorized.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string domain = "https://accounts.google.com";
    string audience = "theaudience";
    // Just to debug/test
    string signingKey = "---- - BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIfujHGitJ\n---- - END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    var certificates = 
    this.FetchGoogleCertificates().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = domain;
            options.Audience = audience;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromHours(48), // This is just for debugging. Maybe we do need a little clock skew if the clock in Google is not aligned with the VD system
                ValidateAudience = true, // Validate the audience, this will change in production to the endpoint URL
                ValidateIssuer = true, // Validate the issuer (Google). If this is wrong, we get a 500 error instead of 40x
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey)),
                /* Stuff I also tried:
                IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
                IssuerSigningKeys = certificates.Values.Select(x => new X509SecurityKey(x)),
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
                {
                    return certificates
                    .Where(x => x.Key.ToUpper() == kid.ToUpper())
                    .Select(x => new X509SecurityKey(x.Value));
                }
                */
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [ASP.NET blog post on JWT Validation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/):

> First, the Authority property should not be set on the
>   JwtBearerOptions. If it’s set, the middleware assumes that it can go
>   to that URI to get token validation information.

You are leaving the Authority property set, in your code example, which causes the verification library to make a network request to accounts.google.com to get token validation information. If you leave the Authority property unset, it will be forced to use your TokenValidationParameters.

Comment: That worked. A note for others: I expected to have to use the certificate belonging specific to the Google Cloud service account, but that didn't work. Instead I had to use the general Google certificates from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs